Extracting matched data using overlap weights
I have generated overlap weights on R using weightit package, I generally fo regression using weights directly.
But I want to extract the matched data according to overlap weights for demographic analyisis, can that be done?
w.out <- weightit(
  COXMAZE ~ AGE + FEMALE + Congestive_Heart_Failure + Cardiac_Arrhythmia + Pul_HTN + 
    Prior_TIA + Known_CAD + elixsum,
  data = mydata_new,
  method = "ps",
  estimand = "ATO"
)

summary(w.out)
mydata_new <- mydata_new %>%
  mutate(weights = w.out$weights)

I need a way to extract matched data and use it as sperate dataset.

Could you elaborate on what you mean by extracting the matched the matched data? WeightIt generates propensity score weights. The weighit object has the data that was used but in effect you will just return the og dataset. Matching on the other hand will return a slightly different dataset because it is pruning the data based on some criteria
